# Better way than MD5?

Tags: javascript, comparison, md5, equals

I'm wondering is there a quicker, more efficent way of comparing two text files to check equality than comparing the MD5 of two files? I'm using Javascript.

Comment: In what context? Where are the text files located? Are they resources you are fetching from somewhere? If so, using what method?

Comment: I'm fetching them from a HTML page which my browser is on.

Comment: Is the MD5 implemented on the server or in the client?

Comment: Client. Can't be done on the server for other reasons.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have to calculate the MD5 of the files each time you do this, you might as well just check that the lengths are the same, then compare them byte by byte. Calculating the MD5 (or any other hash) means running through the whole file anyway.

Pseudocode:

```
bool filesAreSame(file1, file2) {
    if (file1.length != file2.length) return false;
    for (int i=0;i<file1.length;i++) {
       if (file1[i] != file2[i]) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be interessted in the Wikipedias [Comparison_of_cryptographic_hash_functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_cryptographic_hash_functions)

From: wikipedia:Sha1sum

> However, sha1sum is still usable for
>   general-purpose file checksumming, and
>   is widely considered more secure than
>   MD5 or a CRC.

And from: wikipedia:Md5sum

> md5sum should not be used in
>   situations where security is important

An interesting article about speed can be found at omnifarious.livejournal.com/363945.html.

The result was:

> SHA-1 was actually faster on most of them (Operating Systems)

Comment: Your link doesn't answer the question, and your answer should contain some more information than just a link - unless someone asks for a link, specifically.

Comment: I just wanted to show, that there are many more has functions available. Some of them are faster and more efficient. So I posted the link. If you would have given me one more minute you could have seen the extra edits I did. Thanks for downvorint anyway.